# how to create directory on hadoop machine running on vm using hadoop api

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a java client program that creates directory, but when execute the program its creating directory on my local machine even i have configured fs.defaultFS to vm url that matches core-site.xml.

here is the sample program that creates directory.

```
import java.io.IOException;
 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

 public class Mkdir {

 public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException

 {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://testing:8020");
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
    Path path = new Path("/user/newuser");
    fileSystem.mkdirs(path) ; 
  fileSystem.close();
 }
  }
```

Comment: http://blog.rajeevsharma.in/2009/06/using-hdfs-in-java-0200.html

Answer (score 0):

add this two file in your code

```
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.addResource(new Path("/home/user17/BigData/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
            conf.addResource(new Path("/home/user17/BigData/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));

        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

give path according to your system

Comment: I have included both the configuration, but still its not pointing to vm(hadoop running), instead of that it creates directory on local windows system.